# Why are these values sometimes undefined?

Tags: string, list, perl

I'm fairly new to Perl and am working on a project to further my learning. It's a little console word game (translated from a python project of mine), and part of the logic requires to draw a random letter from a pool that is 98 characters long.

Running the functions individually, I've never had an issue, but when I try to loop it into a list it occasionally fails. Running with warnings on tells me that some of these are undefined, but I can't for the life of me figure out *why*. Here's an MRE:

```perl
package Random;
sub choice {
  shift;
  my ($str) = @_;
  my $random_index = int(rand(length($str)));
  return substr($str,$random_index,1); #fixed variable name
}
package Player;
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = { "name" => shift, "letters" => {fillList()} };
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}
sub drawCharacter {
  my $freq = "aaaaaaaaabbccddddeeeeeeeeeeeeffggghhiiiiiiiiijkllllmmnnnnnnooooooooppqrrrrrrssssttttttuuuuvvwwxyyz";
  my $choice = Random -> choice($freq);
  return $choice;
}
sub fillList {
  my @ls = ();
  for (0..6) {
    push @ls, drawCharacter();
  }
  return @ls;
}
sub getLetters {
  my ($self) = @_;
  my $arr = $self -> {letters};
  return %$arr;
}


package Main;
my @players = ();
for (0..12){
  my $player = Player -> new("Foo");
  print($player->getLetters(),"\n");
}
```

BIG EDIT: Adding the object I'm using. This is verifiably *not working*. Warnings:
"Use of uninitialized value in print" and "Odd number of elements in anonymous hash". This is where I think the issue lies.

The list returned by `fillList` sometimes is missing an item or 2, and in some circumstances even 3 or 4 items are missing. Does anybody know what's going on here? The python one hasn't failed once.

If the python analogue would be helpful, I can include that here too.

Comment: *Running with warnings on ...* Never turn warnings off, that is just a bad idea.

Comment: Always warnings, always strict.

Comment: What is `$copy`? Where does it come from?

Comment: `$copy` does not exist. Most likely a typo, coming from posting code that is not tested beforehand. You should never do that, it just wastes people's time.

Comment: I've run `7 == grep defined, fillList() or die;` 10_000 times but it never failed.

Comment: @TLP, It's a console app so I turned them off _temporarily_ to test the visuals of the app. There were known errors I was working around. I know it's good practice to use both warnings and strict.

Comment: What is this "bank string"? Do you mean to say that you use another string in your code? Just do this: Take the code you are showing. Run it with the appropriate input and get your expected failure. Then post that *exact* code, and the *exact* errors and output.

Comment: @TLP I added some more code, and now the error is reproduced. Feel free to take a look, I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: @zdim I attached more code to make this make sense, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @zdim, fixed it--I guess it just didn't get caught in the copy+paste. Would you mind elaborate/linking to a site about packages and classes? I'm not super sure what's wrong with it yet, I'm super new

Comment: @TLP just fixed that, sorry about the mix-up. Missed it in the copy-paste from my editor.

Comment: The error comes from you using a hash reference where you want to use an array reference. Starting here: `my $self = { "name" => shift, "letters" => [fillList()] };` Note that I changed `{ }` to `[ }` instead. Also changed `%` to `@` where this array is used. That removed all warnings. Still... I am not so sure these packages are up to par. But I am not all that good with Perl's package stuff.

Comment: @zdim I'll look into it! I'm well acquainted with OOP in several other languages, perl is just the latest in the series heh. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from using a hash ref where you should have an array ref:

```
my $self = { "name" => shift, "letters" => {fillList()} };
#                                          ^          ^-- wrong brackets
```

This is what the warning talks about:

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at foo.pl line 22.
```

You want to change that to:

```
my $self = { "name" => shift, "letters" => [fillList()] };
#                                          ^          ^--- creates array ref
```

And also the line which uses this array

```
return %$arr;
```

Where you need to change `%` to `@`.

```
return @$arr;
```

After those fixes, the code runs without errors for me.